# cannot find symbol variable MyWebViewClient

Tags: java, android, android-webview

I am trying to create a webview android application with Android Studio and Java. I had it working but then realized that I also needed to navigate between pages on the website. Looking at https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview, I found that I had to add this line of code: `myWebView.setWebViewClient(MyWebViewClient);`. but, this line of code is giving me an error.

I have tried cleaning and rebuilding the project. I have tried importing `import android.webkit.WebViewClient;`. I have tried `MyWebViewClient myWebviewClientInstance = new MyWebViewClient();
myWebView.setWebViewClient(myWebviewClientInstance);` and `myWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());`. But, all of this does not seem to work.

Here is my code:
activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

And my MainActivity.java file (IN THIS FILE IS THE ERROR):

```
package com.rosaliewessels.mywebview;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

       myWebView.setWebViewClient(MyWebViewClient); \\ERROR on MyWebViewClient



        myWebView.loadUrl("https://www.mijnmedicijn.nl");



    }
}
```

And AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.rosaliewessels.mywebview">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

How can I resolve the error and be able to navigate between the pages on the website? I am really new to Android Development and help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here with this -

**myWebView.setWebViewClient(MyWebViewClient); \ERROR on MyWebViewClient**

Whenever we use setWebViewClient method, we need to create its inner class, just create it like this -

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
```

**//  Following line will be change**

```
    **myWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());**
    myWebView.loadUrl("https://www.mijnmedicijn.nl");
   }

 private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
  }  
}
```

// For performing click operation inside the mobile web view, you can enable Java script like this-

```
 **myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);**
```

Hope it may help you, Happy Coding :)

Comment: To freely be able to roam the website, is there any other code I should add? Because it seems to be really slow and is not showing everything I click. The error did disappear though:)

Comment: @RosalieW We use these code for webview :) , it depends on us if we want to customize it, is that code worked for you?

Comment: Yes the code worked and the error disappeared. But, at the top of the mobile web page, there is a menu button that does not want to unfold? Is there any way I could fix that?

Comment: This is dutch language :), so you want to show that menu button which is top right corner of  cijjn.nl or want to perform opreation on that?

Comment: Haha yes, that's right. At the right top corner, there is a menu button if you use the website on a mobile device. This button is not expanding/unfolding in the web view. I want the user to be able to navigate using that button (but it somehow is not working on the android web view)

Comment: If you would prefer seeing the English version of the website, that is at www.meamedica.com :)

Comment: @RosalieW , please check my updated answer, for performing click opreation inside mobile web view, you need to enable java script like that :)

Comment: Thank you so much! That was it! (I could have thought of this but oh well) :)